# Counter is skipping post when I still want it visible

Tags: posts, query, query-posts, count

I am showing the 5 latest posts on my homepage. I am using a count so that on the 3rd post it shows a div which will be completely seperate to the blog posts. However rather than the 3rd post continuing on after this div has been added, it skips it and goes onto the fourth post. Any idea how to keep the latest 5 posts showing but just add a div after the second one?

```
<?php $my_query = "showposts=5"; $my_query = new WP_Query($my_query); ?>
            <?php if ($my_query->have_posts()) :?> 
            <?php $count = 0; ?>
            <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $count++; ?>
            <?php if ($count == 3) : ?>
                <div id="latest-news" class="col-lg-4" style="height:480px;">
                    <h2>Latest News</h2>
                </div>
              <?php else : ?>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <article <?php post_class('news-post'); ?>>
                        <div class="innerPost">
                            <a class="postLink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="postDetails">
                                <div class="postDetInner">
                                    <header>
                                        <div class="arrowpan"></div>
                                    </header>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-post-inner">
                            <?php 
                                $category = get_the_category(); 
                                if($category[0]){
                                    echo '<a class="category-link" href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->term_id ).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a>';
                                }
                            ?>
                            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $ID ); ?> </a></h2>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of one post ?>
            <?php endif; //end of loop ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic in your code is wrong. Read your code in plain English.

> If  the current post is number 3, show my custom content, else, show the posts as normal.

What you want is the following

> If the current post is number 3, show my custom content.
>
> Show all my posts as normal

To achieve this, you need only wrap your custom content in your statement. So you need to rewrite your code as follow

```
<?php if ($count == 3) : ?>
    <div id="latest-news" class="col-lg-4" style="height:480px;">
        <h2>Latest News</h2>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

### FEW NOTES ON YOUR CODE

- `showposts` is depreciated in favor of `posts_per_page`
- Do not use `:`, `endif` and `endwhile`. Although it is totally valid php, it is hard to debug as most code editors don't support this syntax. Use the old style curlies (`{}`). they are supported by all code editors and easy to debug
- `wp_reset_postdata()` should go after your `endwile` and before `endif`. The reason for this is, you don't need reset anything if you don't have posts

### ANOTHER APPROACH

Just as another idea, you can use the `the_post` action to add your custom content before post 3. You can try something like this as well

```
add_action( 'the_post', function ( $post ) 
{
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->post != $post )
        return;

    if ( 2 != $wp_query->current_post )
        return;

    echo '<div id="latest-news" class="col-lg-4" style="height:480px;">
        <h2>Latest News</h2>
    </div>';    
});
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you so much for your help and the additional tips too.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it worked out for you. Enjoy :-)

Comment: Would you possibly be able to take a look at this for me? 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191438/wp-query-inside-an-existing-wp-query-stops-next-post-showing